# Translate n xor expressions to CNF?

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, logic, formula

I have n xor expressions:

```
a xor b xor c xor d...
```

I want to translate to cnf:
The answer of cnf can be found here:

```
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a++XOR+b++XOR+c+XOR+d+
```

I want to write a converter, but how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

The minimal CNF form is a list of terms, each of which, when they evaluate to 0, force the entire CNF to zero. If you change any input bit of a XOR b XOR c XOR .. you change the output, so for xor its regions all force 0 for just one combination of bits, and there are an exponentially large number of them - with n inputs there are 2^(n-1). Are you prepared for this?

Given that interpretation, you can construct the formula for CNF form by just taking e.g. (a = 0 and b = 0 and c = 1 and d = 1) => 0 and turning this into the term (a OR b OR NOT c OR NOT d). You then do this for everything that produces 0 and and them all together.

You can get a more manageable solution if you change the problem slightly. If were trying to give a XOR b XOR c XOR d = 0 to a sat solver you could introduce new variables to stop the exponential blowup something like this: (a XOR b = y) AND (y XOR c = z) AND (z XOR d = 0) where even if (a XOR b = y) doesn't boil down very nicely the result doesn't get massively worse as you increase the number of variables.